# Fill an input function to the right dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of values, lets say:

[image]

And I want to achieve this:

[image]

the number of rows I manually select, but the columns could vary, and I input the function and number of columns into a another function, in this case `=SUM(A1:A5)` and `4` for the function below:

```
Sub FunctionFill()

    Dim myFunction As String: myFunction = "=SUM(A1:A5)"
    Dim Numvendors As Integer: Numvendors = 4
    Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, Application.ActiveCell.Column).Resize(, Numvendors).Formula = myFunction
    
End Sub
```

This works as a macro.

How do I change this sub into a function that takes `Numvendors` and `myFunction` as inputs and outputs the range.

Comment: So, you modified your question by incorporating the answer provided by @WayneODonnell and are now expecting a new answer. This is against the rules of this site.

Comment: Are the arguments of the function the formula and a number representing the number of columns? Which range should be the result? The range where the formula is to be processed, in your example, the range `A1:D5`?

Comment: Its meant to repeat the function in `myFunction` to the right, `Numvendors` amount of times, starting from the active cell.

Comment: I understand that, but you require a range as the output. Which range?

Comment: Any range I guess, as long as its (1, `Numvendors`) dimensional you can specify its location anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Do you want to write the results to the range? Do you maybe want the function to return an array of the results? Could the first argument be just a range address while the result would be the reference to its first row? Maybe share a practical example of what the procedure should do.

Comment: Yes it can return an array or range, the first argument is a string of the function to be carried out, so`"=SUM(A1:A5)"`, practically it should all be in the original question. You select a cell and it outputs the range/array etc...

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

You don't really need range as well as cells.
You can fill all the cells at once using Resize rather than using a loop

.Formula tells it you want to set the cell formula.

```
Function FunctionFill(myFunction As String, NumVendors As Integer)

    Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, Application.ActiveCell.Column).Resize(, NumVendors + 1).Formula = myFunction

End Function
```